# .env file in ASP .net 4.7.2 has issues if there is = inside the value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In my .env file i have a key value pair as `myvalue=myday?fido=2`.I have to add the query param viz., `?fido=2` for testing purposes only.

However the application fails.Its due to the presence of **=** in the value.How can i get around this without having to change my code just for the testing part.I have tried enclosing it in single as well as double quotes.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since the equal sign is the delimiter between key and value and so causes a parsing error if more than one is detected per line, I would suggest you string encode your values.

You might look for an encoding that won't contain the equal sign as possible padding character, so as to avoid the same issue.

One such encoding that comes to mind is base58.